# Insert new line, not getting text from textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm having problems with a web app. I have a gridview connected with SQL datatable and in the footer I have textboxes (or dropdownlists) and an "insert" button. The problem occurs when I click on the button, and want to insert new line in my SQL table. It does not read text (we need to put in some strings) from textboxes. Of course insert does not happen, since some of the data must not be null.
I have the same problem with Editing rows.

this is my code:

Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvUser" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowDataBound="gvUser_RowDataBound"
OnRowCommand="gvUser_RowCommand" ShowFooter="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblLname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lname") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewLname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ShowHeader="False">
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAdd" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Insert"
                    Text="Shrani"></asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void BindGV()
{
    //bind the SQL table to the GridView (no problem here)
}

protected void gvUser_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //here I bind the dropdownlist (did not include it in code snippet, 
    //since firstly I need to get text from textboxes
}

protected void gvUser_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("Insert"))
    {
        TextBox txtNewName = (TextBox)gvUser.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewName");
        TextBox txtNewLname = (TextBox)gvUser.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewLname");

        string NewName = txtNewName.Text; //this strings come up empty (just "")
        string NewLname = txtNewLname.Text; //it should read from textboxes

        AddRow(NewName, NewLname);

        BindGV();
    }
}

private void AddRow(string name, string lname)
{
    //insert row into SQL datatable
}
```

EDIT: 
Well it works now. Found a simmilar problem, and the author said he was able to get it work with adding EnableViewState="false" to the Gridview.

I tried and it worked. :)

Anyone here able to answer why would this work? And how will this correspond with other gv functions?

Comment: OnRowCommand is named differently - gvUser_RowCommand in code behind, GVuporabniki_RowCommand in gridview

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake when typing here. The gridview actually has a lot mor columns, but I thought if I include 2 as an example here, it will be enough to figure the mistake.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @John: Sorry about that. Will keep in mind or future questions I might have.

Comment: I found a fix. Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code - based on `e.Item.FindControl`

```
 if (e.CommandName.Equals("Insert"))
    {
        TextBox txtNewName = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtNewName");
        TextBox txtNewLame = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtNewLname");

....

    }
```

Comment: I get this error: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)